# Matlab and any, difficulties in understanding

Tags: c++, matlab, any, armadillo

I can't understand what this code does:

```
if any(scale==0)
   loglik = -inf;
```

I have to translate it into C++ with the Armadillo library, that does not have an `any` function so I was wondering how to do it.

I've read the [matlab manuals](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/any.html), but it is still confusing.
I've then tried with this test case:

```
if any([*]==0)
   1
else
   0
end
```

using as * those values (and many more):

```
[0 0;0 0]
[1 0;0 0]
[1 0;1 0]
[1 0;0 1]
[1 1;1 1]
```

but I am still confused and results are dark.. any explanation please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab (and Armadillo) represent booleans as `0` for `false` and `1` (or really anything that's not `0`) for `true`. They both define an `==` operator over matrices/vectors that does component-wise comparisons and outputs a matrix of booleans. `any` is taking in that matrix of booleans and checking if any are non-zero.

Armadillo does not appear to have `any`, but it does provide `find` which can be used to implement `any`:

```
!find(X, 1).is_empty()
```

is equivalent (albeit possibly slower): it constructs a vector of at most one non-zero elements ([documentation for find](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find)). If it's empty, then there are no non-zero elements, so `any` would return false.

Comment: The `1` just makes it stop after the first non-zero index it finds. Otherwise it will compute all of them. No idea if it actually matters for performance.

Comment: an example of my matrix on with i have to make any is *[ 1.0000   0.0100   0.1000   0.1000   0.1000   0.1000; 1.0000   0.0100   0.1000   0.1000   0.1000   0.1000]* and with negation(**!**) and 1.. it does not work, don't understand exaclty why

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: no problem, with the code in the first comment it works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.910, Armadillo has the [any()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#any) function.